# Regex Match based on two strings using AND

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching, and-operator

I want to extract commands from a string. The commands I need contain specific ids 124 and 123 and also specific flag od and xy. So I want to extract all those commands which `contained my ids [123|124]` **and** `my flags[od|xy]` only.

String: `Z124xy54;Z123od33;Z123od343;Z251od541;Z251ab541;`
Regex: `Z[^;]*?(od|xy)[^;]*?;`
Required Output: `[Z124xy54;  Z123od33;  Z123od343;]`
But Current Output : `[Z123xy54;  Z123od33;  Z123od343;  Z251od541;]`

I know why its happening that way but don't know how to solve this. Any one could help please

Another Sample:

```
Z124xy54;Z123od33;Z123od343;Z251od541;Z251ab541;Z123od343;
Z124xy54;Z123od33;Z123od343;Z251od541;Z251ab541;Z123od343X
```

Comment: Why don't you need `Z251od541;`? It matches your regex.

Comment: my thoughts exactly

Comment: And title doesn't really tell anything about the problem

Comment: sorry, my mistake.

Comment: let me edit question

Comment: What's your logic reason matching `Z123od343;` but disqualifying `Z251od541;` ?

Comment: ok, guys please check my quesiton now and please remove -ve rating whoever did that if my question is clear now.

Comment: why not do the same or option with the numbers? `(123|124)`?

Comment: [`/\bZ12[34](?:od|xy)[^;]*;/g`](https://regex101.com/r/JTPcRW/2)? Where can the IDs appear? Could you just explain the syntax of these strings?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you please explain answer because above string was a sample and I need to understand to implement it in real way.

Comment: To give you an answer please provide specifications. The majority of us do not like to play guessing games. Post the real life example string at least and specify what you need to extract from it and *why*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
(Z(?:123|124)(?:xy|od).*?(:?;|$))
```

1. Start with Z  => (Z)
2. Match 123 or 124 without capturing group => (?:123|124)
3. Match zy or od without capturing group => (?:xy|od)
4. Match anything except newline untill first ; or end of string found without capturing group => (:?;|$)

Working Demo : https://regex101.com/r/AugDZT/2

Comment: could you please explain your answer?

Comment: @WasimA. Added explaination

Comment: what do you mean of without capturing group?

Comment: i mean it will not save to group

Comment: @WasimA. Updated answer

Comment: thanks, it works, if anyone want answer for non-capture group like me, here is best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon